# Pass data from activity to recyclerview in fragment kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

As part of one of my courses I need to display a recyclerview listing the car models according to the selected brand. I manage to retrieve the id of the brand in my activity. However, when I want to send it to my fragment containing the recyclerview I get an error. The screenshot is below.

It's obviously coming from my supportFragmentManager in the activity but I can't find a solution. If anyone can help me that would be great.

Thank you

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8CDE.png)

**MainActivity2.kt**

```
package ca.ulaval.ima.tp3

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import ca.ulaval.ima.tp3.databinding.ActivityMain2Binding

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMain2Binding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val idMarque = intent.getStringExtra("idMarque")
        println(idMarque)
        val fragment = ModèleFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("idmarque", idMarque)
        fragment.arguments = bundle

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.recyclerView_main, fragment).commit()

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

**ModèleFragment.kt**

```
package ca.ulaval.ima.tp3

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_marque_list.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 */
class ModèleFragment : Fragment(), OnModeleClickListener {

    private var columnCount = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            columnCount = it.getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT)
        }

        fetchJson()
    }

    fun fetchJson() {
        val data = arguments
        val idMarque = data?.get("idmarque")
        val url = "https://tp3.infomobile.app/api/v1/brand/"+idMarque.toString()+"/models"

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val lesmodeles = OkHttpClient()
        lesmodeles.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeedModele::class.java)
                activity?.runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerView_main.adapter = MyModèleRecyclerViewAdapter(homeFeed)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_modele_list, container, false)

        // Set the adapter
        if (view is RecyclerView) {
            with(view) {
                layoutManager = when {
                    columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
                }
                //adapter = MyModèleRecyclerViewAdapter(listeDesVoitures)
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onModeleItemClicked(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "ça marche", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val intent = Intent(this@ModèleFragment.requireContext(),MainActivity3::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    companion object {

        // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
        const val ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count"

        // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(columnCount: Int) =
            ModèleFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount)
                }
            }
    }
}


class HomeFeedModele(
    @SerializedName("content")
    val modeles: List<Modele>
)

class Modele(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String
)
```

**MyModèleRecyclerViewAdapter**

```
package ca.ulaval.ima.tp3

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView

import ca.ulaval.ima.tp3.placeholder.PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem
import ca.ulaval.ima.tp3.databinding.FragmentModeleBinding

/**
 * [RecyclerView.Adapter] that can display a [PlaceholderItem].
 * TODO: Replace the implementation with code for your data type.
 */
class MyModèleRecyclerViewAdapter(val homeFeedModele: HomeFeedModele?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyModèleRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            FragmentModeleBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = homeFeedModele?.modeles?.get(position)
        val leModele = item?.name.toString()
        holder.contentView.text = leModele
        holder.contentView.setOnClickListener{
            val context=holder.contentView.context
            val intent = Intent( context, MainActivity3::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("idModele", item?.id)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return homeFeedModele?.modeles?.size ?: 0
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(binding: FragmentModeleBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val contentView: TextView = binding.content

        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + " '" + contentView.text + "'"
        }
    }

}
```

**fragment_modele_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main"
    android:name="ca.ulaval.ima.tp3.ModèleFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ModèleFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_modele" />
```

**ANSWER**

I finally found a solution by using my API directly in the activity without going through the fragment and without using a bundle.

**MainActivity2.kt**

```
package ca.ulaval.ima.tp3

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import ca.ulaval.ima.tp3.databinding.ActivityMain2Binding
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_marque_list.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMain2Binding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        fetchJson()

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    fun fetchJson() {
        //val data = arguments
        val idMarque = intent.getStringExtra("idMarque")
        println("id de la marque" + idMarque)
        val url = "https://tp3.infomobile.app/api/v1/brand/"+idMarque.toString()+"/models"

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val lesmodeles = OkHttpClient()
        lesmodeles.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeedModele::class.java)
                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerView_main.adapter = MyModèleRecyclerViewAdapter(homeFeed)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}



class HomeFeedModele(
    @SerializedName("content")
    val modeles: List<Modele>
)

class Modele(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String
)
```

**ModèleFragment.kt**

```
package ca.ulaval.ima.tp3

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_marque_list.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 */
class ModèleFragment : Fragment(), OnModeleClickListener {

    private var columnCount = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            columnCount = it.getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_modele_list, container, false)

        // Set the adapter
        if (view is RecyclerView) {
            with(view) {
                layoutManager = when {
                    columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
                }
                //adapter = MyModèleRecyclerViewAdapter(listeDesVoitures)
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onModeleItemClicked(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "ça marche", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val intent = Intent(this@ModèleFragment.requireContext(),MainActivity3::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    companion object {

        // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
        const val ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count"

        // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(columnCount: Int) =
            ModèleFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the line 50 exactly when you parse from Json the body response, which can be null.
Please check the following approach:

- Check that body is not null, its values as well, you can do this setting a break point on `val body = response.body?.string()` and checking its values.
- I see HomeFeedModele(val models: List) has all values to non-nullable, please check the values you receiving on that json response are never null, if they are, make the values nullable and initialise them as null.

If it continue failing, share the json response on the comments and I will try to help you.

Comment: I just tried your solution and got the idea to manage my API and my recyclerView directly from my activity without communicating to the fragment through a bundle. This solved my problem, I'm putting the solution at the bottom of my post in case anyone is interested.
Thanks for your help !